# Where to keep calculations on data in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Where to keep calculations on data in Symfony?

For example I have entities:

```
City:
- name (string)
- men (int)
- women (int)
- streets (Collection)

public function getMenAndWomenIn33rd() 
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($this->getDistricts() as $district) {
        if ($district == '33rd') $count++;
    }
    return $this->getMen() + $this->getWomen() + $count;
}

Streets:
- city_id (relation)
- name
- district
```

And for example I would like to count the average number of men and women on the street in a district 33rd and pass this to template.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $city = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->findOneByName('New York');

    return $this->render('city/index.html.twig', array('name' => $city))
}
```

Template:

```
{% block body %}
   City: {{ city.name }}
   //others data...
   33rd: {{ city.getMenAndWomenIn33rd()  }}

{% endblock %}
```

Method getMenAndWomenIn33rd()  should be in `City entity`? Maybe in repository? In repository should be operations on  database? Maybe in service? I know that it can not be on the controller, because the controller should only pass data.

I know - I can do it in repository with GROUP BY, but I prefer have only one query (findOneBy - next I change it to querybuilder with Joins).

Comment: Once you make a calculation in the controller, you can pass that value on to the Twig view, it doesn't have to be stored in a database if I understand your situation correctly.  For simple calculations, you can also just pass the queried value from the database and make the calculation directly in Twig.

Comment: You might want to consider custom repository methods.

Answer (score 1):

The good approach is to store all the business-logic in the service-layer.
I prefer the following structure of a symfony application:

1. Controllers/Commands can only get a user input, run basic validations it and pass it to a service.
2. Services (some call them Managers). Manage all the business logic. They don't know anything about data storage and about a code that will use them. In order to get data, they use data-access-layer e.g. repositories. Services input, in my opinion must be of simple types or simple DTO.
3. Data-access layer. This layer knows about how the data is stored, can get a data, hydrate it to a structure (e.g. Entity) and pass it back to a service.

In your case, there can be a CalculationsService, that can ask a repository for all the men or women in a district, calculate all the data you need and pass int back to a controller as simple int or DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Entities should be very straight forward. No calculations should be done there, as this role of the entity to keep the state.

You can create a specific service where all calculation will be done, or you can create a TwigExtension if you need them only to display some data and no usage in other places of your application. Of course you can create a service and then inject it in TwigExtension. Depends on your needs.